# TextFields and labels not align correctly

Tags: ios

I'm new to IOS development and I can't figure out how to fix this problem. I have a few TextFields and labels added, but two of them appear one top of the other just like in the picture when I run the app: the Gender TextField and the Type TextField.

What can I do to align them correctly on runtime ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Making this in code or IB?

Comment: do you have a tabbar or navigation bar on this view controller?

Comment: Hmm, it seems that disabling the AutoLayout helped me. Thanks to the post that was deleted.

Comment: A better approach is to leave auto layout on, and use it correctly. If you put vertical spacing constraints between each of your views, they will maintain the correct spacing on any size screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aligning issues mostly caused by (on Interface Builder);

a) Autosizing (Auto Layout since iOS 6) is messing with your aligned objects, when you design your app for regular size and use iphone 5 size, or vice versa.

b) When you use tabbar or navigation bar and do not select relevant 'Status Bar' / 'Top Bar' / 'Bottom Bar' from Attributes Inspector > Simulated Metrics, which also messes aligned objects.